# how can I make a connection to a database in the main function and then reference it from other functions

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have recently begun delving into the world that is database programming with C++ & Qt, and I've got a question. I know the answer is probably very basic but I can't seem to figure it out.

How can I make a connection to a database in the main function and then reference it from other functions?

Basically when the program first launches I create a instance of the main window, but before showing it, I connect to a database for later queries. I then show the window. Great but no when I try to make the window populate with data I can't because the connection name is outside of the scope of the function.

How could I make that global, I thought it would be by default because I have constructed the database in the main function witch every other class or function should inherit from(or at least I thought).

I'm still learning so I'm sure it is just a small misconception I have on how inheritance works.

Here is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setHostName("LOCALHOST\\TestServer");
db.setDatabaseName("TestConnection");

w.show();


return a.exec();
}
```

And later on in the main window I create a dock which I can populate with data pulled from a database. Here is were I need to preform the Query in the mainwindow::Createdock function

```
void MainWindow::createDockWindows()
{
QDockWidget *rightDock = new QDockWidget(tr("Tasks"),this);
rightDock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

todoGroupBox = new QGroupBox(rightDock);
todoGroupBox->setTitle(tr("To-Do List"));

QSqlDatabase(db.open());
if (db.open())
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Connected","Connection to the Database was Established\n"
                             "\nStatus: Connected");
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Not Connected","Connection to the Database could not be Established\n"
                             "\nStatus: Not Connected");
}

todoList = new QListWidget(todoGroupBox);
todoList->addItems(QStringList()
        << "Install Outlook on Jessies Computer"
        << "Purchase 2 Licenses of Adobe Suite"
        << "Contact UPS to put in a ticket to their IT dept.");

addToDoLabel = new QLabel;
addToDoLabel->setText(tr("Sample Text"));
addToDoButton = new QToolButton;
addToDoButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/gedit-icon.png"));
addToDoButton->setToolTip(tr("Create a new task"));
addToDoButton->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+Shift+t"));

QHBoxLayout *todoButtonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
todoButtonLayout->addWidget(addToDoLabel,0,Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
todoButtonLayout->addWidget(addToDoButton,0,Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);

QVBoxLayout *todoLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
todoLayout->addWidget(todoList,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
todoLayout->addLayout(todoButtonLayout,0);

todoGroupBox->setLayout(todoLayout);
todoGroupBox->setMaximumSize(todoGroupBox->sizeHint());

}
```

Comment: Database connections are global, they "just work" if you use the plain default stuff and don't use multiple connections. Can't know what you're doing wrong without seeing the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this in QT would be to name the database connection:

When you create `add` a database using QT you can call [`addDatabase()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase-2) specifying a database connection name.  When you do that you can in any class use [`database()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqldatabase.html#database) and provide a database handle to the one you have created in `main()` or any other place in the code since both methods are static.

**Example**

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "MyDB");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=myaccessfile.mdb");
if (db.open()) {
    // success!
}
```

Then anywhere in the code you can do:

```
QSqlDatabase localdb = QSqlDatabase::database("MyDB");
```

which will give you the handle to the one you have opened above.

Comment: Could I see an example of what you mean, I'm sorry, I am just still new to c++ and qt and db programming. Do you really mean the QDatabase() function because I cannot find just database, and how would I correctly put in the parameters to access db. Would they just be "db"?

Comment: I still cant get it to work. I added the error string to the popup and it says the driver is not loaded. Does anybody know why that would be?

Comment: @Rob This is a completely different issue.  If you don't have the driver loaded it is quite likely it's not installed.  Plus based on your code you never `open()` the database, so the connection is not active anyway.

Comment: Thanks I just got it working... It was because I called to set up the main window with the connection before I actually established the connection. Minus that little detail your answer worked great Karlson, thanks for the help